# How do I make Heroku detect the distube

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, discord.js, distube

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       npm ERR! code ETARGET
       npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @distube/soundcloud@^0.8.0.
       npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
       npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.iyUJC/_logs/2022-10-15T23_44_56_907Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
```

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the 0.8.0 version tag?

```
No matching version found for @distube/soundcloud@^0.8.0
```

Heroku is correct: [that version does not exist on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@distube/soundcloud), and [GitHub agrees](https://github.com/distubejs/soundcloud/releases). It looks like this project jumped from 0.2.2 right to 1.0.0:

- 1.2.2 (current)
- 1.2.1
- 1.2.0
- 1.1.1
- **1.0.0**
- **0.2.2**
- 0.2.1
- ...

Update your dependency so it points to an available version, ideally the latest release, then redeploy.